# IBM Cloud and Database for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ibm-cloud

I'd like to know how to get the string connection of my MongoDB database to use with Mongoose, I was looking for and there are old info, and when I though I found a good documentation, well, it doesn't work(this is the [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-connection-strings#connection-strings)), the command doesn't exist, this is the comand [ **ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections example-mongo -u admin
** ] specifically ***CDB***

I hope someone can help me please.

Comment: If you add the string you've tried and also show what the docs also say (so people do not have to click the link and look for it) you have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Have the same problem and wonder if you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the connection string to Databases for MongoDB using the `ibmcloud cdb` plugin but must be installed first. You can install it using the command:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-databases
```

Then you can start using the `cdb` plugin. After that, you can get your MongoDB connection strings with:

```
ibmcloud cdb cxn <name of mongo deployment>
```

For the CA cert you'll need to connect, the plugin will decode it for you with:

```
ibmcloud cdb cacert <name of mongo deployment>
```

You'll also be able to change the `admin` password as well.

Or, you can go to your IBM Cloud dashboard, click on your Databases for MongoDB database, select "Service credentials" on the left panel of your MongoDB management panel, and then create some service credentials. This service credential will give you a username, password, the CA cert (encoded), and connection strings, as well.